Is there a left extensional relation which is not right extensional?
A binary relation $R$ on a set $S$ is defined to be left extensional if the following property holds, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ refer to elements in $S$: $(\forall x)(\forall y)((\forall z)(zRx \leftrightarrow zRy) \rightarrow x=y)$. Right extensional is the same thing, except with $xRz$ replacing $zRx$, and $yRz$ replacing $zRy$. My question is, what is an example of a binary relation that is left extensional but not right extensional?

Here is an example with a set (and not a proper class).  Take $S=\{a,b,c\}$ with

$aRa$, $aRb$,
$bRa$, $bRb$,
$cRb$, $cRc$.

The relation $R$ is left extentional since the three sets

$\{x\in S\mid xRa\} = \{a,b\},$
$\{x\in S\mid xRb\} = \{a,b,c\},$
$\{x\in S\mid xRc\} = \{c\}$

are distinct.
It is not right extensional since
$\{x\in S\mid aRx\} = \{x\in S\mid bRx\} = \{a,b\}.$
There does not seem to be an example if $S$ has less than three elements.

Sure. Consider a model of $\mathsf{ZF-Extensionality}$ with at least one urelement. $\mathsf{Pairing}$ ensures upwards (= left) extensionality with respect to $\in$, but the existence of urelements kills downwards (= right) extensionality with respect to $\in$.

Nice example! But I think left and right should be the other way around(?)
